# Delegate UICollectionView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I can't decide who should be delegate of UICollectionView which is subview of UITableViewCell. UITableView has its controller as delegate inside a storyboard. The UITableViewCell (with UICollectionView) has its own xib.
But who should be delegate of UICollectionView inside his UITableViewCell?

I tried to link the delegate of the UICollectionView on the UITableViewCell, but that didn't work.

Comment: What exactly you mean "I tried UITableViewCell, but that didn't work.". Edit your question with what you have tried so far ? Please Check this link too if it helps: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generally:

whatever that needs to use the delegate callbacks...should be the delegate, whatever object that holds the datasource needs to be the datasource. *usually* that's a UIViewController.

### Specifically:

Your case is slightly different. Your hierarchy is something like this:

ViewController >> TableView & TableViewCell >> CollectionView.

What you could do is make your viewController the delegate of the collectionView. But that's not recommended, since you're skipping one level of hierarchy. I would suggest that you make the tableViewCell the delegate of the collectionView and then make the controller the delegate of the tableViewCell again, though this would be some custom delegate.